# Why does carousel not work?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out why the carousel is not working. I am thinking the problem is script placement, but can't put my finger on it. I also have functioning navbar code that I have omitted. Help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Sams</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="css/logo.png" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="css/logo.png" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="css/logo.png" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src=js/samex_script.js></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The carousel presented in the above code works.  Have you inspected the code on your end to look for errors; perhaps related to `samex_script.js` which loads above all the jQuery / Bootstrap includes?

Comment: If @RobertC's comment doesn't help, perhaps `jquery-3.2.1.slim.js` is not the one to use, perhaps `jquery-3.2.1.js` would work.

Comment: thanks guys. do you think that browser sync may be the issue?(I've tried the above two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually working as expected, the 'slides only' Bootstrap carousel just takes a while (about 5 seconds) to trigger:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Sams</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src=js/samex_script.js></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you swap out to a carousel that can be controlled manually, here's a working carousel with controls:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Sams</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/600" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src=js/samex_script.js></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do you know if browser sync may cause an issue? It does not work on my browser sync

Comment: Browser sync shouldn't cause an issue, but I'd try isolating the problem; the snippet above is working for me across each of the main browsers (excluding Safari, which I can't test). I'd recommend starting from that as a blank template just through your browser, then slowly introducing things like additional code and browser sync until you can identify what conflicts. But the above is certainly working :)

Comment: Ahhh thanks. I was overriding bootstrap css with mine.